# Binding for AndTinder library

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a binding library for android AndTinder library. But I am getting the following error

```
Error CS0507: 'Com.Andtinder.View.SimpleCardStackAdapter.GetCardView(int, Com.Andtinder.Model.CardModel, Android.Views.View, Android.Views.ViewGroup)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'Com.Andtinder.View.CardStackAdapter.GetCardView(int, Com.Andtinder.Model.CardModel, Android.Views.View, Android.Views.ViewGroup)' (CS0507)
```

To fix the above error , I added the following line to Metadata.xml

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='Com.AndTinder.View']/class[@name='CardStackAdapter']/method[@name='GetCardView']" name="visibility">protected</attr>
```

But this has not fixed. I would appreciate if someone could give me hints on how to fix this error

Answer (score 1):

The base class is protected. So you want to fix this by changing the C# version to protected as well.

Based on the package: `package com.andtinder.view;`

And the MethodName `getCardView`: https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards/blob/master/AndTinder/src/main/java/com/andtinder/view/CardStackAdapter.java#L69

`<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.andtinder.view']/class[@name='CardStackAdapter']/method[@name='getCardView']" name="visibility">protected</attr>`

Overall it seems like you just need to ensure your case sensitivity and this should work!